# SSRS repeated differing headings

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

[SSRS Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l48JH.jpg)

I have some 24 different posting types and I'm trying to get them to change within the header when the posting type changes.

Where it says, **Posting Type: Client Transfer To Office** I have the following expression:

```
="Posting Type: " +
LCase(Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value) + Space(1) +
Switch(Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value="Client Transfer To Office", Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value,
Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value="Client Payment", Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value,
Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value="Client Receipt", Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value,
Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value="Client Interest", Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value,
Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value="Deposit Transfer To Client", Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value,
Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value="Client Transfer To Deposit", Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value,
Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value="Client Transfer To Client", Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value,
Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value="Office Transfer To Client", Fields!ptl_postingtypename.Value, ETC, ETC.
```

The first value ("Client Transfer To Office") shows but it's not changing to the next posting type.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the point of the **SWITCH** is since it just seems to be returning the same field for all possibilities.

I don't know why but I have run into a similar situation where the header **only seemed to be evaluated once**.

I worked around this by having the Header reference the **Page Name** and putting my names in the **Page Name** property.

Expression for the **Text Box** in **Header**:

```
=Globals!PageName & IIF(Globals!PageName = "P4P Total Payout", " - " & Parameters!YEAR.Value & IIF(Parameters!QUARTER.Value = 5, " Final", " Q" & Parameters!QUARTER.Value), "")
```

Then I put the actual name in the **Page Name** property of my table.

[image]

This gives me my results in Excel with the Header and it matches my tab name.

Of course you'd need to have it page by your `ptl_postingtypename` to make it work correctly.

[image]